# Swift - Programmatically refresh constraints

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint, tabbar

My VC starts with `stackView` attached with `Align Bottom to Safe Area` .

I have tabBar, but in the beginning is hidden `tabBar.isHidden = true`.

Later when the tabBar appears, it hides the `stackView`

So I need function that refresh constraints after `tabBar.isHidden = false`

---

When I start the app with `tabBar.isHidden = false` the `stackView` is shown properly.

---

Tried with every function like: `stackView.needsUpdateConstraints() , updateConstraints() , setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` without success.

---

Now I'm changing the bottom programatically, but when I switch the tabBarIndex and return to that one with changed bottom constraints it detects the tabBar and lifts the stackView under another view (which is not attached with constraints). Like is refreshing again the constraints. I'm hiding and showing this stackView with constrains on/off screen.

I need to refresh constraints after tabBar.isHidden = false, but the constraints don't detect the appearance of the tabBar.

As I mention switching between tabBars fixes the issue, so some code executes to detecting tabBar after the switch. Is anyone know this code? I tried with calling the methods viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewWillLayoutSubviews without success... Any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to create an outlet of bottom align and change its constant value when you show tabbar.

Comment: Don't want this method. I want to refresh the constraints.

Comment: Is your `tabBar` an object added to your view? Or, is your VC one of the tabs of a `UITabBarController` with the tab bar hidden? Or, is your VC embedded in a navigation controller and you refer to the bottom bar as a `tabBar`?

Comment: UITabBarController is MAIN Controller and on index 0 of the tabBar is the stackView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This amateur approach fixed my bug... :D

```
tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 1
tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0
```

---

Or with an extension

```
extension UITabBarController {

    // Basically just toggles the tabs to fix layout issues
    func forceConstraintRefresh() {
    
        // Get the indices we need
        let prevIndex = selectedIndex
        var newIndex = 0
    
        // Find an unused index
        let items = viewControllers ?? []
        find: for i in 0..<items.count {
            if (i != prevIndex) {
                newIndex = i
                break find
            }
        }
    
        // Toggle the tabs
        selectedIndex = newIndex
        selectedIndex = prevIndex
    
    }

}
```

Usage (called when switching dark / light mode):

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    
    tabBarController?.forceConstraintRefresh()

}
```

Comment: This might be a hack, but it works really well actually!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update view's layout, you can try **[layoutIfNeeded()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded)** function.

Answer (score 0):

after updating stackView constraints call this method:

```
stackView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: he is not updating constraints ... he just want his stack to adjust with show and hide of tabbar bro

Comment: No worries I will spend some of my reputation for bounty and some PRO will answer the question :D

Answer (score -1):

Apple's `Human Interface Guidelines` indicate that one should not mess around with the Tab Bar, which is why (I'm guessing) setting `tabBar.isHidden` doesn't properly update the rest of the view hierarchy.

Quick searching comes up with various `UITabBarController` extensions for showing / hiding the tab bar... but they all appear to push the tabBar down off-screen, rather than setting its `.isHidden` property. May or may not be suitable for your use.

I'm assuming from your comments that your VC in tab index 0 has a button (or some other action) to show / hide the tabBar?

If so, here is an approach that *may* do the job....

Add this `enum` in your project:

```
enum TabBarState {
    case toggle, show, hide
}
```

and put this func in that view controller:

```
func showOrHideTabBar(state: TabBarState? = .toggle) {

    if let tbc = self.tabBarController {
        let b: Bool = (state == .toggle) ? !tbc.tabBar.isHidden : state == .hide
        guard b != tbc.tabBar.isHidden else {
            return
        }
        tbc.tabBar.isHidden = b
        view.frame.size.height -= 0.1
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.frame.size.height += 0.1
    }
}
```

You can call it with:

```
// default: toggles isHidden
showOrHideTabBar()

// toggles isHidden
showOrHideTabBar(state: .toggle)

// SHOW tabBar (if it's hidden)
showOrHideTabBar(state: .show)

// HIDE tabBar (if it's showing)
showOrHideTabBar(state: .hide)
```

I would ***expect*** that simply pairing `.setNeedsLayout()` with `.layoutIfNeeded()` after setting the tabBar's `.isHidden` property should do the job, but apparently not.

The quick frame height change (combined with `.setNeedsLayout()`) *does* trigger auto-layout, though, and the height change is not visible.

**NOTE:** This is the result of ***very*** brief testing, on one device and one iOS version. I expect it will work across devices and versions, but I have not done complete testing.

Comment: It's not an option for me to change the frame of the view