# How to reload view of selectedViewController in UITabBarViewController when hiding/showing TabBar manually?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue and I'm not sure how to approach this. I have a dynamic custom UITabBarController and I'm setting its viewControllers like this

```
setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: false)
```

Is working fine but I also want to hide the tabBar under certain scenarios. For this I'm just doing this:

```
tabBar.isHidden = true
```

So far so easy. But I realised that the current selectedViewController has some buttons attached to the bottom using some constraints and they're not being updated when the tab bar is hidden or  displayed again. If I change to another tab and then go back, the view is refreshed and everything is fine, so I tried using `selectedViewController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()` once the tab bar visibility changes, but didn't work.

Anyone can give an idea of what's happening? Thanks.

Comment: try selectedViewController?.view.setNeedsDisplay() this will redraw your views.

Comment: Didn't work. Also tried `selectedViewController?.view.setNeedsLayout()` with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried reloading the layout of the tabBar itself? While reloading the view, the tabbar should not be a part of it, hence reloading the tabBar.

Comment: You mean the TabBar or the TabBarController? I tried reloading the layout of the UITabBarController's view (which contains the TabBar and also the container where the selectedViewController is displayed, but nothing changes.

Comment: You might try this (potential) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60567108/6257435